# how to loop a random number in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, random

when I try to loop some functions it get stuck on the randomvariable() ,
how can the random number work on loop   without I need to  refresh the page everytime

```js
function randomvariable() {
  randomvariable = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomvariable;
}



function launchfunctions() {
  var count = 0;
  while (count < 10) {
    randomvariable();
    count++;

  }
}
launchfunctions();
```

```html
<div id="demo" ></div>
```

Comment: Most likely it's erroring as `randomvariable` is not declared.

Comment: @Sid *is redeclared

Comment: @Sid Its declared and its getting overridden in function

Comment: @zexurity Please add a habit of checking console for any errors.

Comment: what @Rajesh said... randomvariable is defined as a function in global scope, and within the function you're referencing the same function and changing the value to a random #.

Comment: The question unfortunately is misleading. Are you asking why your code is failing? Methods? Strategies? Instead,i read `"pls do my work for me"`, which defeats the point of this website. We want you to learn,too.

Comment: @clifton_h it is a bit misleading, but having him noticed that the function only runs a single time and seeing the error code in the snippet makes the answer even more obvious

Comment: If the OP updates the question to reflect this, i would offer an upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're redefining `randomvariable`, use `var` or call your variable something else.

```
function randomvariable() {
    var randomvariable = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomvariable;
}
```

or

```
function randomvariable() {
    mynum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mynum;
}
```

Although note that you should always use the `var` keyword when defining variables, it has been omitted in the second example to show how adjusting just your variable name could resolve the issue.

**Note:**

- Declaring a variable without `var` will make it global in non-strict mode. This is the reason that using `var` inside the function will work.
- Using the same variable names for a function and a variable make your code confusing and reduces readability. Use a better naming convention.

Comment: it worked properly in beginning then it make for me probleme for other function am learning javascript by my own so I have little difficulty when I have bug

Comment: when I've turn it to no global the random work properly but the next function it have score formula , I receive NAN in alert  and  when i work without the var it work properly

Answer (score 0):

you are changing the property of the `randomvariable` function to variable with global scope so, when the flow entered into the randomvariable function the property get changed and reports an error msg. If you use `var` the variable is declared within the scope you are in (e.g. of the function).

I have modified the code to show the random numbers.

```js
function randomvariable() {
  var randomvariable = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += randomvariable + "-";
}

function launchfunctions() {
  var count = 0;
  while (count < 10) {
    randomvariable();
    count++;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="launchfunctions()">
  <div id="demo"></div>
</body>

</html>
```